# Removing type from union in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the following type that I gather through other types:

```
type Example = {
    id: string;
    foo: (string | Type1)[];
    bar: (string | Type2)[];
    baz: string | Type3 | null;
    description: string | null;
}
```

I would like to refine this type by getting rid of the `string`'s in the `foo`, `bar` and `baz` keys.

Is it possible to create a utility function that can map over keys, and if the value union contains `string`, remove `string` so it only returns the remaining union values?

Comment: Removing `string` from `(string | Type1)[]` is a different operation than just removing it from `string | Type1`.  What about `(string | Type1)[][]`?  Or `{x: {y: {z: (string | Type1)}}}`?  How nested do you need this to be?  It would also help if you provided a [mre] that defined `Type1`, `Type2`, and `Type3`.  For all I know those types are themselves things with `string` properties that need filtering.

Comment: Wait, and you don't want it removed from `description` or `id`?  How can we detect which unions you want `string` removed from and which you don't?

Comment: Type1, Type2 and Type3 are all object types. To detect, the only way I can think of is by passing the key names that need to be processed explicitly.

Comment: Please define `Type1`, `Type2`, and `Type3` in your code. It matters because if any of those types have `string` properties then it could affect how the processing takes place.  It's still not clear to me how to generalize taking `string` out of the *elements* of an array type.  My question about `(string | Type1)[][]` and `{x: {y: {z: (string I Type1)}}}` remains; if you want to hardcode the processing for properties that appear directly and for properties that appear as elements of a single array type, that's easy enough, but the type operation starts looking quite ad-hoc.

Answer (score 1):

The main helper type here will be `Exclude<Union, Type>`:

```js
type A = Exclude<string | number, string> // ✅ number
```

But from what I understand, this won't be enough since you need to exclude string **only for unions and not when type string is alone**.

So we need another type to check if type is a union before removing `string` from it:

```
type ExcludeFromUnionIfNotOnlyType<Union, Type> = Exclude<Union, Type> extends never ? Union : Exclude<Union, Type>
```

Now we need to parse the object and take care it removes `string` from `Union` but also `Union` arrays:

```js
type RemoveStringFromUnionInObject<T extends Record<string, any>> = {
  [K in keyof T]: 
    T[K] extends any[] // if it's an array
      ? ExcludeFromUnionIfNotOnlyType<T[K][number], string>[] 
      : ExcludeFromUnionIfNotOnlyType<T[K], string>
}

type Parsed = RemoveStringFromUnionInObject<Example>

// TESTS
type Id = Parsed['id'] // ✅ string
type Foo = Parsed['foo'] // ✅ Type1[]
type Bar = Parsed['bar'] // ✅ Type2[]
type Baz = Parsed['baz'] // ✅ Type3 | null
type Description = Parsed['description'] // ✅ null
```

**Here is the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAehAIBEEEBVuAFwJ4AcCm5ZvQRnALzgDe4KGuAXGQE4CumAvkjljgEyElkfWL1MWGNhgDMXUuXSi+A8MyGYAogA8AhgFtUAG0xFiwcEfABLACbUAzvxMA7AOYBuQ8YBmAe3fUAFNZp37cAAfETwASgBtAF1nY3AAIzUaHz8A4ND2SJiXI0SALysbB3TsMXTbOm1tWOMzdEsAY39URBN3W0L-YpCKqucFMHAAWWgASQA5LABNAAUlRXBVBu06OoAxGncNAFVbNttR13H3RAB5W21kUvQAHl39gBpQgD4uJZW6u732p+vX9BUiHQtjMlnAtnQADd0DRwAB+cD3drgajvVa3JG2X44Z7AUAQWCzJTgNanABK4FOACEAFJKADCsAWZPQGnc0IAykV7BstpjRrZTvEAFboBqIG6wcAAoEgsEshruGhmG6pBxPNS2ZDPV76FwRADSpls4AA1uhkO5XFgotQclhDVFpYDgaDwJrkNFwIMTNaTIgAORgzXumg0NTIe1GBFo9abHbfA5HE7nS7XSWOiIVDTxGFRJ5q+zPL1RlGLFTLdG8hP7Q7HM4XK44DMG-PgQu4hRScAzJKWdBmLgstmc7nV-mCkViiWqTQ6dC4-FYJQc2AchajQdEXs0ftmCIB8wBp2DQCg5O3uQs1p4uDu9wePO5j96IOfrrhogsqUlb32BwfEhoZ8zwyT9u2-PJf13f8A3yYDX1CcQekqbQFkgeomhMFp9ig+8AzqRpmladp4PAc9elQoA) with the final code**